# RecyclerView notifyDataSetChanged() updates both adapters when I call this method on one

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have two adapters:

```
private StreamingNowAdapter mStreamingNowAdapter;
private UserStreamingNowAdapter mUserStreamingNowAdapter;
```

When I load them with Arrays

```
mStreamingNowAdapter = new StreamingNowAdapter(mEventId, mEventName, 
mEventPreview, mNumberViewers, mContext);

mUserStreamingNowAdapter = new UserStreamingNowAdapter(mUserId, 
mUsername, mProfilePic, mStreamingUserNumberViewers, mContext);
```

and call notifyDataSetChanged(); how come when I call this method on one adapter, both adapters become notified and displayed?

I only called the method on the first adapter

```
mStreamingNowAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and it loads my data into my second recycler mUsersStreamingNowAdapter without me calling notifyDataSetChanged on the second adapter.

Is this a bug or is it supposed to be like this?

**Edit1**: Two separate recyclerviews, both adapters attached to their own recyclers.

```
RecyclerView mRecyclerViewStreaming = 
view.findViewById(R.id.fraghome_recycler_streaming_now);

RecyclerView mRecyclerViewFollowing = 
view.findViewById(R.id.fraghome_recycler_followed_users);

mRecyclerViewStreaming.setLayoutManager(new 
LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

mRecyclerViewFollowing.setLayoutManager(new 
LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));

mRecyclerViewStreaming.setAdapter(mStreamingNowAdapter);
mRecyclerViewFollowing.setAdapter(mUserStreamingNowAdapter);
```

I've checked the layout multiple times to make sure both the recyclerview's id's are not identical. Still can't figure out why this is happening.

Comment: how many recyclerviews are there? is there only one? are you attached both adapters to one recyclerview?

Comment: Hello David. You're going to need to provide a little bit more context here. How and were are these adapters used? Do you have two RecyclerViews? How's the layout? Are they contained in the same activity or fragment? Who maintains the data?

Comment: Two separate recyclerviews, both adapters attached to their own recyclers. Both are in the same fragment. Edit above

Comment: It shouldn't do this. I'd recommend you try using a `ListAdapter<T, K>` (provided by the framework) and use a DiffUtil  (vs. the brute force of notify... in the entire adapter). Needless to say, *that has nothing to do with this*, and your issue is indeed strange, but hard to see how it's happening without either seeing the entire project or performing some testing. [This sample project's adapter](https://github.com/Gryzor/GridToShowAds/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/neutobo/recyclerviewwithads/ThingAdapterWithAds.kt) may help you see how easy is to implement ListAdapter.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini Thanks for confirming that it's not suppose to do this. I will go back to debugging!

Comment: @MartinMarconcini I've been trying to find the issue for the past couple of hours and can't figure out why. Could you check out my adapter real quick? https://github.com/Alice-ww/TestAdapter2

Comment: I see a series of problems with the code you posted in that repo, but *at first quick sight*, I didn't see anything that may be directly causing this. Of course, it can be a different number of factors, and that'd be hard to detect without further testing. I will add an answer to highlight things that would immediately raise my eyebrows if I were reviewing someone else's code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A correctly managed RecyclerView and its required artifact (an Adapter, its data, etc.) should not interfere with another correctly managed RecyclerView or any other component for what is worth.

Unfortunately, the shared code you provided is not sufficient to determine what could be happening in your project.

To the best of my knowledge, RecyclerView adapters don't talk to each other in any way so a `notifyDataSetChanged()` on an adapter, should have no impact whatsoever on another adapter, regardless of where said adapters are declared (assuming they are different instances, of course).

All this being said, I'll offer you my personal comments about the code you posted. Please don't take it personally, for I'm reviewing the code, not the author, from a pure technical point of view based upon my experience with Android.

#### Fragment

It immediately caught my attention to see that a Fragment, a component known for being completely wild when it comes to lifecycle management and state, has so many responsibilities.

It starts by having no less than eight array lists, and managing two recyclerviews, and its respective adapters, and even the LayoutManagers used by the lists.

Not happy with having to manage all this, this Fragment also needs to handle a networking layer, error handling (not yet implemented), and data storage (in memory for now).

Because you may have put this together really fast simply to illustrate a case, I will let the fragment in peace for now.

#### Data

You're putting a lot of stress on your fragment and adapters by splitting the data in a very inefficient way. 4 array lists, one per field? What?

```
             for(HomeFragmentPojo.StreamingNow streamingNow : streamingNowArrayList){
                    mEventId.add(streamingNow.getEvent_id());
                    mEventName.add(streamingNow.getEvent_name());
                    mEventPreview.add(streamingNow.getEvent_preview());
                    mNumberViewers.add(streamingNow.getNumber_viewers());
                }
```

Why are you doing this?

If you have a StreamingNow object that has all 4 fields.

Why don't you have a `ListAdapter<StreamingNow, ViewHolder>()` that simply takes a list of `StreamingNow` objects?

You can simply do `adapter.submitList(...)`  to pass the list once you get it and the adapter (when properly created) will do the right thing.

If you ever update the list, you simply submit it again, and the adapter will calculate the difference and only update the rows that need to be updated.

The **BIND** method, is also simple, because it would look like: (pseudo code)

```
viewHolder.eventName = getItem(position).name
viewHolder.viewerCount = getItem(position).viewerCount

//For the image...
Glide.with(mContext)
    .load(getItem(position).preview)
    .apply(RequestOptions.centerCropTransform())
    .into(viewHolder.preview);

...
```

You get the idea.

Based upon the properties I see, your StreamingNow "pojo" kinda looks like that

```
class StreamingNow {
   String id;
   String name;
   String preview; //maybe an URL? You use Glide so in the bind method, use it.
   String viewerCount;
}
```

When I look at your *other* adapter, I see that it has the same data...

Id, Name, Pic, Count of Viewers.

There is no need to use a different adapter, you can reuse the same adapter assuming they have to behave the same way; if the Users adapter has to do something different on click, for example, you could pass the min information needed for the adapter to decide what to do when an item is clicked. Or better yet, you could simply pass a generic Listener so the adapter simply calls "this item "X" was clicked". Because these adapters aren't here to make decisions and call framework things, they have a lot of work in their plates, and this is not and should not be their responsibility.

Whoever manages, creates, and maintains these adapters (so far, your Fragment) should be the one in charge of doing this. Or even better yet, a ViewModel or Presenter should receive this and make an informed decision.

In any case, the click event inside the adapter is not the biggest problem here, and it will work anyway.

What I am trying to leave written here, is that your problem is a lack of separation of concerns between components.

The smaller and more concrete your classes are, the easier it is to replace them, test them, debug them, enhance them, etc.

You're throwing all your code in a big place. If you separate it, it's a lot easier to keep it under control.

### So, what's the deal?

- I suggest you take a step back, enhance your RecyclerView to use a `ListAdapter`
- I wouldn't perform the network request in onCreate, instead do it in `onViewCreated` or similar, because during onCreate in a Fragment, there's no guarantee that the view will be created. (Remember when I told you Fragments were a pain?).
- I wouldn't have that network code in the Fragment to be honest; it's quite simple to add a ViewModel and have the data there. Then you can have the ViewModel request the data during onCreate, but you'll only get the LiveData from it when your lifecycle allows it... which is the whole point of LiveData and observing it.
- If this sounds like a lot of work, it may as well be, especially if you are new to Android. But it will pay off.

Good luck!

Comment: This...this is absolutely gold tbh. First off I want to thank you for taking your time to write all of this out. Personally I actually PREFER answers that criticize  my code because if no one tells me what I'm doing wrong, I will keep writing it over and over without ever knowing. I have also never gotten an answer like this before on SO and I don't think I will ever again. Lastly where should I look for resources that do things in the correct way? Right now I'm just looking at youtube/SO to building my project and as you can already tell, my code would be thrown out in a real environment.

Comment: Hey David, thank you. I suggest people willing to do Android development, to spend a little bit of time reading about [Android Fundamentals](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals) (not always 100% up-2-date for it's very generic, but still valid). And then, once you have a basic grasp, try to see what can be useful from the vast array of options [JetPack](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/) offers. Remember, you don't need to learn everything... just look at ViewModels, LiveData to get started w/MVVM  (the recommended there) and why it's "good" (or not).

Comment: Thanks Martin much appreciated :) Also peeped your profile and see you're from SF haha. Lived there almost my entire life and currently in the Southbay now

Comment: Thank you for reminding me to update my profile (I no longer live in the USA) :p (update: it was updated) :)